# How to generate a report with a list of test cases covering each method in the code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, sonarqube, jacoco

I need to generate a report with all the methods (both public and private) in the code and a list of test cases covering each method.
I am using Java 8 for actual code and groovy for unit tests.

I am using Sonarqube which gives whether the line is covered. It doesn't show what test cases are covering this line. Anyway, I wanted the list of tests per method and not per line.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**
I am using Jacoco which gives lines covered by individual unit test case and lines covered in a method in actual code by test cases. 
Please let me know whether there is a way I can get a report which gives all the test cases that cover a given method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jacoco](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/)- a code coverage tool which is free, and can generate a code coverage report

It has plugins for maven and gradle so that you can integrate it into your build process.
Later on sonar plugin should pick this report and show in sonar

Comment: Thanks, @Mark Bramnik. I am using Jacoco and getting other useful metrics. Do you know how we can generate a report with a list of test cases covering each method in the code in Jacoco?

Comment: Its what jacoco really has to do, its a core functionality. Usually the build tool that runs the tests instruments the code with jacoco and it produces its reports. You haven't specified a build tool, but if you use maven, for example, than there is a maven plugin https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html that can be defined in pom.xml. For gradle a similar solution should exist

Comment: I use Maven. I found many reports regarding the percentage of coverage of the code and individual files as in above mentioned link but, not per methods. Also, I couldn't find or generate any report which could give a list of test cases per method. Could you please point me to a web link if you have one? Thanks!